# Не могу найти ошибку в коде Python

Tags: python-3.x

Есть файл формата: число число число

Программа выбирает наибольшее и записывает в другой файл

Вот код:

```
input_file = open('INPUT.TXT', 'r')
input_string = input_file.read()
input_file.close()
input_list = input_string.split(' ')
biggest = str(max(input_list))
output_file = open('OUTPUT.TXT', 'w')
output_file.write(biggest + '\n')
output_file.close()
```

На Python 3.6.2 всё прекрасно работает.

Надо чтоб работало на 3.4.3 И вроде работает, но в файл результат пишет неверный, какой - сам не знаю ибо посмотреть нет возможности.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Откуда тогда известно, что пишет неверный результат?

Comment: @Эникейщик: код не работает и в Питоне 3.6, потому что числа и строки по разному упорядочены: `sorted('1 10 2'.split())` vs. `sorted(map(int, '1 10 2'.split()))`

Comment: @jfs Спасибо, помогло!